# Translate area mouse coordinates to the the Node Editor's blackboard coordinates?

Tags: python, node-editor

I'm trying to to add a node from a custom made panel which pops from a pie menu. And I want the node to appear at my mouse's location (see `bpy.context.active_node.location` below).

The problem is that 'mouse_region_x' and 'mouse_region_y' give me the x and y mouse coordinates according to the area's size. And as its size may vary, this would give me, each time, a different offset from the cursor when the node is placed. I want my mouse's coordinates of the Node Editor area to be translated to the Node Editor's "internal" blackboard coordinates.

```
    e = get_event()

    if context.material != None:
        bpy.ops.node.add_node(
            type="ShaderNodeGroup",
            use_transform=True,
            settings=[{"name":"node_tree", "value": "bpy.data.node_groups[\"%s\"]" % node_group_datablock_name}]
            )
        bpy.context.active_node.location = Vector((e.mouse_region_x, e.mouse_region_y)) # Need the coordinates here.
```

Any idea how to achieve this?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Only partially. This code gives you the coordinates of the mouse inside the Node Editor's space:
`bpy.context.active_node.location = context.space_data.cursor_location`
My problem is since I'm opening a pie menu, then another panel from one of the pie's buttons so I can append a node tree, and the problem with the code above is that it takes into account the coordinates of where I clicked first just before I opened the pie menu, instead of where my mouse is now in the "pie button > panel space".

Answer (score 4):

this'll solve it for you:

```
def invoke(self, context, event):
    region = context.region.view2d  
    ui_scale = context.preferences.system.ui_scale     
    x, y = region.region_to_view(event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y)
    self.x,self.y = x /ui_scale,y/ui_scale
    return self.execute(context)
```

Then when you want to use it:

```
def execute(self,context):
    new_node.location.x = self.x
    new_node.location.y = self.y

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Huge thanks for this. It's working perfectly now!
Here's the code that worked in my case:

```
e = get_event()

[...]

ui_scale = context.preferences.system.ui_scale
x, y = context.region.view2d.region_to_view(e.mouse_region_x, e.mouse_region_y)
x, y = x / ui_scale, y / ui_scale
bpy.context.active_node.location = Vector((x, y))
```