# Create node and have the node follow the mouse

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a node in the shader editor and have the created node follow the mouse position until left click, basically replicating the shift+a method in the gui.

I assume this must be run as a modal operator somehow?

```
import bpy

class CreateNode(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "tmp.create_node"
    bl_label = "Create node"
    bl_options = {"UNDO"}
    bl_description = ""

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        '''
        Get the mouse position.
        https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218096/translate-area-mouse-coordinates-to-the-the-node-editors-blackboard-coordinates
        '''
        region = context.region.view2d  
        ui_scale = context.preferences.system.ui_scale     
        x, y = region.region_to_view(event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y)
        self.x,self.y = x /ui_scale,y/ui_scale
        return self.execute(context)
    
    def execute(self, context):

        mat = context.material
        node_type = "ShaderNodeTexImage"

        nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes

        node = nodes.new(node_type)
        node.select = True

        # This will set the node to the mouse pos.
        # How to keep this live and have the positon follow the mouse
        # until left click?
        node.location.x = self.x
        node.location.y = self.y
        
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar behavior to `bpy.ops.node.add_node(use_transform=True, type="ShaderNodeTexImage")`

after run the script, go to Shader Editor press `F7` to test

```
import bpy
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class

def get_current_loc(context, event, ui_scale):
    x, y = context.region.view2d.region_to_view(event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y)
    return x / ui_scale, y / ui_scale

class CreateNode(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "tmp.create_node"
    bl_label = "Create node"
    bl_options = {"UNDO"}
    bl_description = ""

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        node_type = "ShaderNodeTexImage"

        try:
            mat = context.material
            nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes

            bpy.ops.node.select_all(action='DESELECT')

            node = nodes.new(node_type)
            node.select = True
            # nodes.active = node  # uncomment to also activate
            node.location = get_current_loc(context, event, context.preferences.system.ui_scale)
            # do other thing on nodes here
        except:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Can't add node")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        bpy.ops.node.translate_attach_remove_on_cancel("INVOKE_DEFAULT")

        return {"FINISHED"}
    


def register():
    cls = CreateNode
    register_class(cls)

    # add a keymap to test. If there is a conflict with F7, choose other
    key_map_type = "F7"

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km_name = "Node Editor"
        km = kc.keymaps[km_name] if km_name in kc.keymaps else kc.keymaps.new(name=km_name)

        if not any(e.idname == cls.bl_idname  for e in km.keymap_items):
            kmi = km.keymap_items.new(cls.bl_idname, type=key_map_type, value='PRESS')

if __name__ == "__main__":  register()
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot! This seems to work exactly like I wanted. Sorry for the late reply, lots of stuff got in the way.